# How to proportionally resize absolute elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position, absolute

I have a background image and a few other elements positioned absolute.

When I resize the browser I would like the absolute elements to resize themselves and keep their proportion.

```html
<div style="position:relative">
  <div style="background: transparent url('http://via.placeholder.com/600x300') no-repeat;
    width: 100%; height: 300px; background-size: contain
  "></div>
  
  <div style="width : 100px;height : 75px;position : absolute; background: green;top : 50px;"></div>
  <div style="width : 100px;height : 75px;position : absolute; background: red;top : 100px;"></div>
</div>
```

or https://jsfiddle.net/2sx7nw5d/4/

any ideas? I'm ok with using CSS only or JavaScript

Comment: How about using percentages for width and height?

Comment: Can't do it in my case. Need fix values.

Comment: Do you mean resize relative to its parent div, or resize relative to the document height and width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say that you want the elements to resize, what specifically do you mean?
Should they get bigger/smaller? Stay the same relative size to the page?

If you want them to stay the same relative size to the page, you could use vw or vh units. Like
width: 20vw;
height: 8vw;

If you want to keep proportions within one fixed scale you can use padding like
width: 300px;
padding-bottom: 75%; // <- will always be 75% of whatever the width is.

This wouldn't work if you had content in your elements, then you might be better off just calculating the height using JavaScript.

Comment: I mean get smaller, since the current width and height are the highest they can be. Ill try the vw units. And yeah, i do have content in them.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, after some research. Not sure if it fits your requirement.

Following is the HTML markup.

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <div style="background: transparent url('http://via.placeholder.com/600x300') no-repeat;
    width: 100%; height: 300px; background-size: contain
    "></div>

    <div style="width : 100px;height : 75px;position : absolute; background: green;top : 50px;" class="dyn" data-defaultwidth="" data-defaultheight=""></div>
    <div style="width : 100px;height : 75px;position : absolute; background: red;top : 100px;" class="dyn" data-defaultwidth="" data-defaultheight=""></div>
</div>
```

The required jQuery snippets would be as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var oldWidth = parseInt($(window).width());
    var oldHeight = parseInt($(window).height());

    $("div.dyn").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("data-defaultwidth", $(this).css("width"));
        $(this).attr("data-defaultheight", $(this).css("height"));
    });

    var resizeTimer;

    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        if (resizeTimer) {
            clearTimeout(resizeTimer);   // clear any previous pending timer
        }

        resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            resizeTimer = null;
            var newWidth = parseInt($(window).width());
            var newHeight = parseInt($(window).height());
            $("div.dyn").each(function(){
                var thisWidth = parseInt($(this).data("defaultwidth"));
                var thisHeight = parseInt($(this).data("defaultheight"));
                console.log(thisWidth * newWidth / oldWidth);
                $(this).css("width", (thisWidth * newWidth / oldWidth));
                $(this).css("height", (thisHeight * newHeight / oldHeight));
            });
            oldWidth = newWidth;
            oldHeight = newHeight;
        }, 50);

    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pktk8obb/39/